# Error starting Eclipse on Centos 6 (JVM terminated. Exit code=13)

Tags: linux, centos, java, eclipse

After extract ***`eclipse-jee-mars-1-linux-gtk.tar.gz`*** and running eclipse I am getting following error. I have installed Oracle JDK. What would be the error and solution ?

Java version

```
[root@hithertech eclipse-modeling-mars-1]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Error on running `eclipse-jee-mars-1-linux`

```
Eclipse:
GTK+ Version Check
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /usr/local/eclipse-modeling-mars-1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /usr/local/eclipse-modeling-mars-1//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.1.v20150904-0015/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/local/eclipse-modeling-mars-1/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/local/eclipse-modeling-mars-1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /usr/local/eclipse-modeling-mars-1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 220011
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /usr/local/eclipse-modeling-mars-1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the JVM version (32/64 bit) you use matches the eclipse version (32/64 bit).

I find these lines conflicting.

> `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`
>
> `arch x86`